# Office 365 Global Email Intercept

Tags: c#, email, office365

I am currently looking to intercept emails to whole domain on office 365, however I am not sure if this is possible, - without authenticating all my users and then iterating through the list and connecting as them each time.

Is there a better way than doing this, or am I stuck with only being able to view one mail box at a time?  (ideally I need to look into the mail box with a windows service etc - so I only need to worry about incoming emails.)

Comment: Outbound or inbound, or just "in a mailbox"?

Comment: preferably just in the mailbox...

Comment: Well i guess if they are inbound you could have an smtp thing that sent 1 copy to the user and 1 copy to a mailbox of your choosing, but, ethically there are also rules of reading mails, even at work.